# When does a resource node drop off some profit?

Tags: natural-selection-2

As I am playing as a commander sometimes I always ask myself this question:

Where is the point, when a resource node starts to create profit?
When does it actually makes sense to build a mineral node, when I know it is not in a safe area?

A resource node costs 10 resources. I have no idea how long it takes to generate +1 mineral, I suppose something like 30secs.

So if I would know all parameters I would be able to calculate how long it takes for the resource node to actually drop off some profit and if the risk is worth it.

How do other commanders decide situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes 6 seconds to generate 1 tres (plus 0.125 pres for each person on the team, excluding the commander). This means it takes exactly 1 minute for a resource tower to pay for it's tres cost.

However consider that even if it doesn't last a minute it's not a complete loss as your team will have received pres.